# Can we add the same file to two different records at the same time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, fileupload

I'm using lightning:fileUpload in my lightning component to upload files. Now I need to upload the same file to both parent and child case at the same time. Is there any possibility to do that?

```
<lightning:fileUpload name="fileUploader" multiple="true" recordId="{!v.caseId}" onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
```

Can we specify more than one recordId in lightning:fileUpload tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lightning:fileUpload` component takes only one ID but in the handler for `onUploadFinished` event, you get the Document ID back. You can make another server call to create a new `ContentDocumentLink` object record.

Please note these will be two different transactions so based on the requirement you may need to write your own rollback logic.

Comment: Yes !!! Tried the same !! Worked !!! Thanks alot manjit